# Play a loading animation without losing the iPod music

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I got an app wich include several animations. To load these animations i use the MPMoviePlayerController. 
The problem is that if the user is currently listening to some music with an app in background mode, the MPMoviePlayerController fade out the music, even if my animation didn't include any sounds.

Here is the code i use to instantiate my player

```
NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"anim-geoloc" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];

player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
player.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;
[player prepareToPlay];

[movieURL release];
```

I have tried to change the *useApplicationAudioSession* attribute but it changes nothing.

How can i play my animation without loosing the music playback ? Is there a better way to perform an animation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i figured out what's going out. When you use the MPMoviePlayerController and you want to share the audio session with others apps, you must create an audio session like this.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:NULL];

[session setActive:YES error:NULL];
```

With this, my animation doesn't stop the iPod app's sound anymore.